# Can change the user's email in aws cognito user pool?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, email-verification

I am using aws cognito user pool in my application and users can log in to the app using their email that verified in aws cognito.
Users can change login email and the users must verify the new email.
But users can't change login email in my application now, and I don't know how to solve it.
We need to find a solution to update the email on the AWS cognito and fix it.
How can change the user's email in aws cognito user pool?

Answer (score 8):

You can use [adminUpdateUserAttributes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminUpdateUserAttributes.html) to update user `email` and `email_verified` after that Amazon Cognito sends email again (check [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/signing-up-users-in-your-app.html#managing-users-accounts-email-testing)).

```
const params = {
  UserPoolId: 'UserPoolID',
  Username: 'username',
  UserAttributes: [
    {
      Name: "email",
      Value: "new email"
    },
    {
      Name: "email_verified",
      Value: "false"
    }
  ],
};
const cognitoClient = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider();
const createPromise = cognitoClient.adminUpdateUserAttributes(params).promise();
await createPromise;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [UpdateUserAttribute](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html#updateUserAttributes-property) to update the email

```
 const params = {
        AccessToken: accessToken, /* required */
        UserAttributes: [ /* required */
            {
                Name: 'email', /* required */
                Value: email
            }
       }; 

        const response = await cognito.updateUserAttributes(params).promise();
```

later, you will need to confirm this change using this method  [VerifyUserAttribute](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html#verifyUserAttribute-property)

```
const params = {
        AccessToken: accessToken, /* required */
        AttributeName: attributeName, /* required */
        Code: code /* required */
    };
    try {
        const response = await cognito.verifyUserAttribute(params).promise();
```

This is the best way to change email or some others attributes