# Can users change email when using the email login option on AWS Cognito

Tags: go, amazon-cognito

I am using AWS Cognito and want to know how to use AdminUpdateUserAttributes in Golang to change the email address.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/cognitoidentityprovider/#CognitoIdentityProvider.AdminUpdateUserAttributes

During cognito setup, under "How do you want your users to sign in" header in cognito user pool creation I choose by email.

This post [Can change the user's email in aws cognito user pool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66544422/can-change-the-users-email-in-aws-cognito-user-pool) has an answer for when using the username option.

Answer (score 1):

```
output, err := cognitoClient.IDP.AdminUpdateUserAttributes(&cognitoidentityprovider.AdminUpdateUserAttributesInput{
    Username: aws.String(username),
    UserAttributes: []*cognitoidentityprovider.AttributeType{
        {
            Name:  aws.String("email"),
            Value: aws.String(username),
        },
    },
    UserPoolId: aws.String(cognitoClient.UserPoolID),
})
```

In your case `aws.String(email)` should work.

or

```
output, err := cognitoClient.IDP.UpdateUserAttributes(&cognitoidentityprovider.UpdateUserAttributesInput{
        AccessToken: aws.String(accessToken),
        UserAttributes: []*cognitoidentityprovider.AttributeType{
            {
                Name:  aws.String("email"),
                Value: aws.String(username),
            },
        },
})
```